# Rails Capistrano deploy with and without rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rbenv

Old rails project on production has no rbenv, uses ruby installed manually. I've set a staging for it WITH rbenv, added capistrano-rbenv gem and capistrano staging deploy config params. Now it keeps searching for rbenv folders even while deploying to production and it of course fails.

Is there a way I can configure capistrano not to use rbenv while deploying to production?

Here are my current config files:

**deploy.rb**

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.4.1'

# Git repo URL
set :repo_url, '...'

# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, true

# Don't use sudo
set :use_sudo, false

# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

namespace :deploy do
 ...
end
```

**deploy/staging.rb**

```
# Application name
set :application, '...'

# Use a specific tmp dir
set :tmp_dir, "/home/user_name/apps/#{fetch(:application)}/tmp"

# Deploy to this location
set :deploy_to, "/home/user_name/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"

# Branch to deploy from
set :branch, 'staging'

# rbenv stuff
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.5'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}
set :rbenv_roles, :all # default value

# General
server '...', user: 'user_name', roles: %w{app web db}
```

**deploy/production.rb**

```
# Application name
set :application, 'production'

# Use a specific tmp dir
set :tmp_dir, "/home/user_name/apps/#{fetch(:application)}/tmp"

# Deploy to this location
set :deploy_to, "/home/user_name/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"

# Branch to deploy from
set :branch, 'master'

# General
server '...', user: 'user_name', roles: %w{app web db}
```

**production ruby**

```
production@server_name:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.10p489 (2018-03-28 revision 63023) [x86_64-linux]

production@server_name:~$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Try moving the `capistrano-rbenv` to staging group in Gemfile if you don't already have it there

Comment: @DeepakMahakale it's already in dev group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the gem getting loaded in `production` environment,

Try moving the `capistrano-rbenv` to `staging` group in Gemfile if you don't already have it there.

Also, you must have an entry in Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
```

You need to make it conditional so that you don't end up requiring it in production environment

There is an old issue which solves a similar issue, please take a look

https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv/issues/31

Add this in Capfile

```
if Rake.application.top_level_tasks.first == "staging"
  require 'capistrano/rbenv'
end
```

Comment: thank you, answer from that issue helped. So here's what you have to exactly do:

if Rake.application.top_level_tasks.first == "staging"
  require 'capistrano/rbenv'
end

Comment: @Marat Good to know. I will add that snippet in the answer in case someone else stumbles upon the same issue